# Setting group_by in plotly choropleth

Tags: r, plotly

I am looking to make a choropleth in R with plotly. I would like to be able to select the data which is shown on the map in a legend, like you can do in most plotly charts by setting the `color` argument in `add_trace()`. However, this does not work as `color` is taken for the choropleth fill, of course, and I cannot determine how to otherwise accomplish it. The `group` argument is deprecated and I have not had success with `group_by`.

Reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

sample <- data.table(Region=c("Illinois","Illinois","California","California","Texas","Texas"),
           code=c("IL","IL","CA","CA","TX","TX"),
           Group=c("A","B"),
           Value=rnorm(6, mean=100, sd=6))
sample$hover2 <- with(sample, paste(Region, '<br>', 
                                         "Group", Group, '<br>',
                                         "Value:", Value))

x <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('lightblue')
)
```

My first attempt only shows the `Group` B when hovering over the states.

```
plot_geo(sample, locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_trace(type="choropleth",
    z = ~Value,
    text = ~hover2, locations = ~code,
    color = ~Value
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = 'Plotly map',
    geo = x
  )
```

Then, I found that you can use `group_by` to replace the `group` argument but this just produces the same plot as above:

```
sample %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  plot_geo(locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_trace(type="choropleth",
    z = ~Value,
    text = ~hover2, locations = ~code,
    color = ~Value
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = 'Plotly map',
    geo = x
  )
```

So, I would like to use the `Group` variable to select which data is showing (`Group==A` or `Group==B`). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My suspicion is that this may not be possible. If you don't get an answer to this, maybe consider looking into an alternative to plotly. Perhaps leaflet can do this?

Comment: @dww I think you are right. I am switching over to markers because the choropleth fill isn't that important.